# istream Unhandled exception, stack overflow

Tags: stack-overflow, unhandled-exception, istream

I'm fairly new to C++, and am trying to get the istream to work. I have a class of:

```
class rat
{
private:
    int num;
    int denom;
public:

    rat();
    rat(const int&, const int&);
    rat(const int&);

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const rat&);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream&, const rat&);
};
rat::rat(void)
{
    num = 0;
    denom = 1;
}

rat::rat(const int &n, const int &d)
{
    num = n;
    denom = d;
    simplify();
}

rat::rat(const int &n)
{
    num = n;
    denom = 1;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const rat &r1)
{
    os << r1.num;
    os << "/";
    os << r1.denom;
    return os;
}

istream& operator >> (istream &is, const rat &r1)
{
    is >> r1.num;
    is >> r1.denom;
    return is;
}
```

I also have a .cpp of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
#include "Rats.h"

void main()
{
    rat r1(3,4), r2(2,3), r3;


    system("cls");
    cout << "Please enter a rational number: ";
    cin >> r3;
}
```

My problem occurs whenever it comes across the "is >> r1.num;" line. It gives me the error: Unhandled exception at 0x772d15de in RatClass.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.

Again, I'm fairly new, so have not learned what the possible cause could be yet. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it might be the fact that you're accepting `const rat &r1` but by sending data from the `istream` you would be changing `r1`. You can't change constants. Not sure if this is the issue but that's the first obvious thing that came to mind.

Try this:

```
istream& operator >> (istream &is, rat &r1)
{
    is >> r1.num;
    is >> r1.denom;
    return is;
}
```

**Don't forget to change your definition in the class:**

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream&, rat&);
```